# Apache Camel: routes inheritance - moving code to the super class

Tags: apache-camel

I have the following supercalss `BaseRouteBuilder` where I am handling the common exception. All my routes extends this class `1234Route extends BaseRouteBuilder`. In all my route I am calling at the end a http request to create the order and I am using a format to convert it to JSON. Is it possible in apache Camel to move the format and this conding to the supercass `BaseRouteBuilder`?

```
.marshal(format)
.setHeader(
    Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, 
    constant(org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpMethods.POST)
)
.setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/json"))
.to("http://localhost:8080/orders/create-order")
```

**Superclass - BaseRouteBuilder **

```
@Component
public class BaseRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        //@formatter:off
        onException(Exception.class).process(new Processor() {

            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
              //Coding to enrich the exception error
            }
        })
        
        .handled(true)
        .to("activemq:queue:dead-messages");
        
        //@formatter:on

    }

}
```

***Subclass - 1234Route*

```
@Component
public class 1234Route extends BaseRouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        super.configure();

        JacksonDataFormat format = new JacksonDataFormat();
        format.useList();
        format.setUnmarshalType(DataBase.class);

        //@formatter:off
        from("activemq:queue:1234")
            // my route coding (I have deleted it)
            //.setHeader()
            //.process
            //.bean()

            //This is the common coding I want to move it to the super class.
            .marshal(format)
            .setHeader(
                Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, 
                constant(
                    org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpMethods.POST
                )
            )
            .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/json"))
            .to("http://localhost:8080/orders/create-order");
        //@formatter:on
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RouteBuilder supports inheritance just like any other class, since onException is RouteBuilder scoped it's fine to define it in a base class. I would however advice against or at least be very careful when defining routes in something like BaseRouteBuilder.

You should also mark BaseRouteBuilder abstract and I would also try to give it more descriptive name like RouteBuilderWithGenericErrorHandler.

RouteBuilders are used to create and add RouteDefinitions to CamelContext and you're not limited to using just one RouteBuilder.  Now if you add multiple RouteBuilders to CamelContext that all inherit from BaseRouteBuilder **this will cause BaseRouteBuilder.configure to be called multiple times.**

**This can cause problems like:**

- RouteId conflicts.
- Consumer endpoint URI conflicts.
- Same configuration changes getting applied multiple times.

  - i.e if you use `RouteBuilder.getContext` to modify the CamelContext in some way.

> In all my route I am calling at the end a http request to create the order and I am using a format to convert it to JSON.

If many of your routes share same routing logic you should split that part to separate route and use it like function. It also makes it easier to add route-scope error handling like what to do when orders api isn't responding or the body provided to `direct:createOrder` consumer endpoint is invalid.

```java
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    
    from("direct:createOrderA")
        .routeId("createOrderA")
        // .. do stuff for A
        .to("direct:createOrder");
    
    from("direct:createOrderB")
        .routeId("createOrderB")
        // .. do stuff for B
        .to("direct:createOrder");
    
    
    DataFormat format = ...;

    from("direct:createOrder")
        .routeId("createOrder")
        .marshal(format)
        .setHeader(
            Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, 
            constant(org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpMethods.POST)
        )
        .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/json"))
        .to("http://localhost:8080/orders/create-order");
        
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I build a route for error hanlding without inheritance how will the error handling route be invoked from 1234Route? Please provide me with an example.

Comment: I just want to mention that I used BaseRouteBuilder  as mention in the book (Camel in Action page 491) :)

Comment: Yeah my bad, was under impression that `onException` would be CamelContext scoped like routes are but seems that onException returns `OnExceptionDefinition` which seems to be route builder scoped (i.e linked to each RouteDefinition in RouteBuilder). Then its fine to use it like this, just mark it abstract and give it more descriptive name.

Comment: @PasiÖsterman as you have stated, there might be ID conflicts and I'm currently facing such a problem. My abstract RouteBuilder is a SEDA consumer that also declares an Exception handler. When an exception occurs, the Camel Stacktrace shows the wrong ID of another consumer, that was not used and is not responsible for that exception and I'm wondering why. Not sure if the exchange.getFromRouteId() returns the right ID in that case. Do you have any idea?

Comment: By route id conflicts I mean that if you try to add routes with same ID camel will throw an `FailedToStartRouteException` with message Failed to start route <routeId> because of duplicate id detected. Instead of `exchange.getFromRouteId()`  I would rather use [route-specific exception handling](https://camel.apache.org/manual/exception-clause.html#_advanced_usage_of_exception_clause) as it offers a lot of flexibility even with inheritance.

Comment: @PasiÖsterman thanks. I don't have conflicts, but rather discrepancies. I'm now using `onException` on the abstract route, and the routeId is set by the concrete class. In our case, I send a notification with the exception and use the `getFromRouteId()` to have any identifier for what route was affected, but this is obviously wrong. It's almost randomly giving the id of any of the consumers bac, but the exception can only come from one specific consumer.